# Angular to control printing , no. of times?

Tags: angularjs

I do have a print Service developed using angular js, 
Is there any efficient way that I can mention the no.of times.

Currently I can loop through this code and call n number of times

```
PrintService.printElement("printThisElement");
```

Print service code

```
function printElement(elem) {

   var printSection = document.getElementById('printSection');

   // if there is no printing section, create one
   if (!printSection) {
    printSection = document.createElement('div');
    printSection.id = 'printSection';
    document.body.appendChild(printSection);
   }

   var elemToPrint = document.getElementById(elem);
   //clones the element you want to print
   var domClone = elemToPrint.cloneNode(true);
   printSection.innerHTML = '';
   printSection.appendChild(elemToPrint);
   $timeout(function(){
       window.print();   
   }, 0);

   window.onafterprint = function() {
       printSection.innerHTML = '';
   }

  };
```

Can I loop thru this ?

```
 $timeout(function(){
           window.print();   
       }, 0);
```

Comment: instead of looping this code you can looping inside `printElement` method of  `PrintService`

Comment: updated question Can I loop through print ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your question but from what I understand, your `PrintService` can be called from various controllers within your app. And you want to control the number of times this method can be called.

You can use a global variable, and check its value inside the `PrintService.printElement("printThisElement");` method. If the value exceeds your limit, return an error.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.value('test', 0);  

myApp.factory('PrintService ', ['test', function (test) {

  this.printElement = function () {
    //check 'test' value and then run print code
    //test++ if printing
  }

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$timeout` does not loops the function, `$timeout` used to execute the code inside it only once after a time out.

Instead use a `variable` to `loop` using `if` condition.

**HEre is an example:**

```
var count = 0;
function myFunction() {
    count++;
    if(count > 5) 
    {
        return; // you can either return or execute any other code.
    }
    else
    {
        window.print();
    }
}
```